# ASCII-based OOP blackjack game in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, object-oriented, game, playing-cards

I'm new to programming and have been teaching myself to code for about 6 months. Since I have no one to ask about any of coding-related questions, I may have developed bad habits in the meantime, but I can't tell myself. As such, I wrote a simple blackjack game in Python, to demonstrate how I usually code, and to find out if there is something I should've done (or I shouldn't have done).

This is the start of the code.

```
from random import shuffle, uniform
from os import system, name, get_terminal_size as tsize
from time import sleep
```

This is `Card` class. I don't like `display()` method, because it's too ugly (especially with some fonts that breaks the shape). But I'm not sure how to improve this. I'm also not sure where should I place `sdict` and `color`. Currently, it's a class variable. Should I pull these out of `Card` class and put it on top? And I don't know when exactly I should implement those getters/setters. I just make them every time. Is this a bad practice? Lastly, `uid` is doing nothing currently but I put it there just in case. Should I remove such useless things on main branch and only leave it on test/dev branch?

```
class Card(object):
    sdict = {'S': '♤', 'H': '♡', 'D': '♢', 'C': '♧'}
    color = {'r': '\033[1;31;49m', 'w': '\033[1;37;49m'}

    def __init__(self, suit, rank, uid):
        self.suit = suit
        self.symbol = Card.sdict[suit[0]]
        self.rank = rank
        self.uid = uid
        self.is_red = self.suit[0] in 'HD'
        self.value = 10 + (rank[0] == 'A') if rank.isalpha() else int(rank)

    def __str__(self):
        r = self.get_rank()
        if self.is_red:
            return Card.color['r'] + self.symbol + r + Card.color['w']
        return self.symbol + r

    def get_suit(self, colored=0) -> str:
        if colored and self.is_red:
            return Card.color['r'] + self.suit + Card.color['w']
        return self.suit

    def get_symbol(self, colored=0) -> str:
        if colored and self.is_red:
            return Card.color['r'] + self.symbol + Card.color['w']
        return self.symbol

    def get_rank(self, colored=0) -> str:
        r = self.rank[0] if self.rank != '10' else self.rank
        if colored and self.is_red:
            return Card.color['r'] + r + Card.color['w']
        return r

    def get_uid(self) -> int:
        return self.uid

    def get_value(self) -> int:
        return self.value

    def display(self, hide=0) -> list[str]:
        if hide:
            lines = ['┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓' if not i else
                     '┃███████████┃' if i != 10 else
                     '┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛' for i in range(11)]
            return lines
        pad = ' ' * (self.get_rank() != '10')
        is_alpha = self.get_rank().isalpha()
        sym, val = self.get_symbol(1) + ' ', self.get_value()
        mid_cen = (sym * (val in (1, 3, 5, 9) or is_alpha)).ljust(2)
        midside = (sym * (5 < val < 9)).ljust(2)
        rdiff_1 = (sym * (val in (9, 10) and not is_alpha)).ljust(2)
        row_2up = (sym * (val in (7, 8, 10) and not is_alpha)).ljust(2)
        row_2dn = (sym * (val in (8, 10) and not is_alpha)).ljust(2)
        corners = (sym * (val > 3 and not is_alpha)).ljust(2)
        top_bot = (sym * (val in (2, 3))).ljust(2)
        lines = [
            '┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓',
            '┃{}         ┃'.format(self.get_rank(1) + pad),
            '┃  {} {} {} ┃'.format(corners, top_bot, corners),
            '┃     {}    ┃'.format(row_2up),
            '┃  {}    {} ┃'.format(rdiff_1, rdiff_1),
            '┃  {} {} {} ┃'.format(midside, mid_cen, midside),
            '┃  {}    {} ┃'.format(rdiff_1, rdiff_1),
            '┃     {}    ┃'.format(row_2dn),
            '┃  {} {} {} ┃'.format(corners, top_bot, corners),
            '┃         {}┃'.format(pad + self.get_rank(1)),
            '┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛'
        ]
        return lines
```

This is `Shoe` class, which doesn't do much. I could just handle the job on `Blackjack` class, or merge this into `Card` class, or separate the job into many classes. I'm not sure which task deserves its own class. And should I avoid using the `print` on `__init__`? Also,  is there any way to use type hint with the default parameter value (like `num_decks=6` and `vb=False`)?

```
class Shoe(object):
    def __init__(self, num_decks=6, vb=False):
        print(f'Generating a dealing shoe with {num_decks} decks', end='')
        self.shoe = self.build_shoe(num_decks)

        print('\nShuffling the cards...' if vb else '', end='')
        shuffle(self.shoe)

        print('\nGenerating a random cut' if vb else '', end='')
        self.shoe = self.cut_deck(self.shoe)
        print(f'\nRemoved {52 * num_decks - len(self.shoe)} cards '
              f'({len(self.shoe)} cards remaining)' if vb else '', end='')
        print()

    @staticmethod
    def build_shoe(num_decks: int) -> list[Card]:
        suits = 'Spade Heart Diamond Club'.split()
        ranks = 'Ace 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King'.split()
        shoe = []
        for _ in range(num_decks):
            for suit in suits:
                for rank in ranks:
                    shoe.append(Card(suit, rank, len(shoe)))
        return shoe

    @staticmethod
    def cut_deck(shoe: list[Card], minimum=0.30, maximum=0.50) -> list[Card]:
        cut = uniform(minimum, maximum)
        del shoe[:int(len(shoe) * cut)]
        return shoe

    def get_shoe(self) -> list[Card]:
        return self.shoe

    def get_length(self) -> int:
        return len(self.shoe)

    def deal(self, num_cards=1) -> list[Card]:
        cards = []
        for _ in range(num_cards):
            cards.append(self.shoe.pop(0))
        return cards
```

This is `Hand` class. Should I always try to reduce the number of iterations? For example, `self.total_value`, `self.num_aces` and `self.hand_value` can be calculated in one sweep, but it will result in vertically longer code (though shorter horizontally). Even if the expected number of iterations is low, should I try to reduce it? Also, should I strictly limit the number of characters to 79? or is it merely a suggestion?

```
class Hand(object):
    def __init__(self, hand=None):
        self.hand = [] if hand is None else hand
        self.total_value = sum(c.get_value() for c in self.hand) if self.hand else 0
        self.num_aces = sum(c.get_value() == 11 for c in self.hand) if self.hand else 0
        self.hand_value = 0
        self.set_hand_value()
        self.decision = ''

    def add_cards(self, cards: list[Card]) -> None:
        for card in cards:
            self.hand.append(card)
            self.total_value += (v := card.get_value())
            self.num_aces += 1 if v == 11 else 0
            self.set_hand_value()

    def get_hand(self) -> list[Card]:
        return self.hand

    def get_printable(self, reveal=22) -> list[str]:
        cards = [c.display() if reveal > i else c.display(hide=True)
                 for i, c in enumerate(self.hand)]
        return ['   '.join(c[i] for c in cards) for i in range(len(cards[0]))]

    def get_hand_value(self) -> int:
        return self.hand_value

    def set_hand_value(self) -> None:
        if self.total_value <= 21:
            self.hand_value = self.total_value
        t, n = self.total_value, self.num_aces
        while n and t > 21:
            n -= 1
            t -= 10
        self.hand_value = t

    def get_decision(self) -> str:
        return self.decision

    def set_decision(self, decision: str) -> None:
        self.decision = decision

    def length(self) -> int:
        return len(self.hand)

    def is_busted(self) -> bool:
        return self.get_hand_value() > 21

    def is_blackjack(self) -> bool:
        return self.length() == 2 and self.hand_value == 21

    def is_playable(self) -> bool:
        return not (self.get_hand_value() >= 21 or self.decision in ('s', 'dd'))

    def is_splittable(self) -> bool:
        return self.length() == 2 and self.hand[0].get_value() == self.hand[1].get_value()
```

and lastly, `Blackjack` class and `if __name__ == '__main__':` thingy. It is very messy but I always ended up like this somehow. Maybe it's because I usually don't plan anything ahead and just dive right into coding, but then again, I don't know what exactly I should plan ahead.

```
class Blackjack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nt = name == 'nt'
        self.cls()
        print('\033[1;37;49mWelcome to the game of Blackjack', end='')
        self.shoe = self.generate_shoe()
        self.bankroll = self.get_int_input(
            f'\nEnter your bankroll [$100-$100m] (Default: ${50_000:,}): ',
            int(1e8), 100, 50_000)
        self.min_bet = max(5, self.bankroll // 1000 // 1000 * 1000)
        self.dealer = Hand()
        self.player = [Hand()]
        self.bet = 0
        self.initial_bet = 0
        self.num_round = 0
        self.play()

    def generate_shoe(self) -> Shoe:
        d = 6
        msg = f'\nEnter the number of decks [2-12] (Default: {d}): '
        return Shoe(self.get_int_input(msg, 12, 2, d), vb=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_int_input(msg: str, hi=6, lo=2, default=6) -> int:
        user_input = lo - 1
        while user_input < lo or user_input > hi:
            try:
                tmp = input(msg)
                user_input = int(tmp) if tmp != '' else default
                if not (lo <= user_input <= hi):
                    print('Input out of range. Please try again.')
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid input. Please try again.')
        return user_input

    @staticmethod
    def get_bool_input(msg: str, opt='YN') -> bool:
        user_input = '1'
        while user_input.upper()[0] not in opt:
            user_input = input(msg)
            if user_input == '':
                user_input = opt[0]
        return user_input.upper().startswith('Y')

    @staticmethod
    def take_decision(hand: Hand, msg: str, possibles: list[str]) -> None:
        decision = ''
        if hand.length() > 2:
            del possibles[2:]
        elif not hand.is_splittable():
            del possibles[3:]
        opt = '/'.join(c if i else c.upper() for i, c in enumerate(possibles))
        while decision[:2].lower() not in possibles:
            decision = input(msg + '[' + opt + ']: ')
            decision = possibles[0] if decision == '' else decision
        hand.set_decision(decision)

    def take_bet(self) -> None:
        d = max(self.min_bet, self.bankroll // 1000 // 1000 * 10)
        msg = f'Place your bet (Default: ${d}): '
        self.bet = self.get_int_input(msg, hi=self.bankroll, lo=self.min_bet, default=d)
        self.initial_bet = self.bet
        self.bankroll -= self.bet

    def get_insurance_premium(self) -> int:
        premium = 0
        if self.dealer.get_hand()[0].get_rank().startswith('A'):
            if self.get_bool_input('Do you want to take an insurance [y/N]? ', 'NY'):
                premium = self.initial_bet // 2
                self.bankroll -= premium
        return premium

    def print_board(self, rv=22) -> None:
        self.cls()
        width = tsize()[0]
        print(f'Bet: {self.bet:,}'.ljust((w := width // 3))
              + f'Round {self.num_round}'.center(w)
              + f'Bankroll: {self.bankroll:,}'.rjust(w))

        print(f'\n\nDealer'
              + (rv > 0) * f': {" ".join([str(c) for c in self.dealer.get_hand()][:rv])}'
              + (rv > 1) * f' ({self.dealer.get_hand_value()})')
        print('\n'.join([line for line in self.dealer.get_printable(rv)]))

        for i, h in enumerate(self.player):
            n = f'{(" (Hand " + str(i + 1) + ")") * (len(self.player) > 1)}'
            print(f'\nPlayer{n}: {" ".join([str(card) for card in h.get_hand()])}'
                  f' ({h.get_hand_value()})')
            print('\n'.join([line for line in h.get_printable()]))

    def get_payout(self) -> int:
        payout, dv, lp = 0, self.dealer.get_hand_value(), len(self.player)
        for i, h in enumerate(self.player):
            n = f'Hand {i + 1}' if lp > 1 else 'You'
            hv, dd = h.get_hand_value(), 1 + (1 * (h.get_decision() == 'dd'))
            if h.is_busted() or hv < dv <= 21:
                print(f'{n} lose')
                continue
            if dv > 21 or hv > dv:
                print('Dealer busted. ' * (dv > 21) + f'{n} win')
                payout += self.initial_bet * (2.5 if h.is_blackjack() else 2) * dd
            elif dv == hv:
                print('Tie')
                payout += self.initial_bet * dd
        return payout

    def cls(self) -> None:
        if self.nt:
            system('cls')
        else:
            system('clear')

    def round(self) -> None:
        self.cls()
        self.take_bet()
        self.dealer.__init__(self.shoe.deal(2))
        self.player = [Hand(self.shoe.deal(2))]
        
        if not self.player[0].is_blackjack():
            while any(h.is_playable() for h in self.player):
                for i, hand in enumerate(self.player):
                    if not hand.is_playable():
                        continue
                    self.print_board(rv=0)
                    s = f'(Hand {i + 1}) ' * (len(self.player) > 1)
                    self.take_decision(hand, f'Enter your decision {s}', 'h s dd sp'.split())
                    if (d := hand.get_decision()) != 's':
                        self.bankroll -= self.initial_bet if d in ('dd', 'sp') else 0
                        self.bet += self.initial_bet if d in ('dd', 'sp') else 0
                        if d == 'sp':
                            self.player += [Hand([hand.get_hand()[0]]), Hand([hand.get_hand()[1]])]
                            del self.player[i]
                            break
                        hand.add_cards(self.shoe.deal(1))

        in_play = not all(h.is_busted() for h in self.player)
        self.print_board(rv=1)
        sleep(0.5)
        premium = self.get_insurance_premium() if in_play else 0
        self.print_board()

        while self.dealer.get_hand_value() < 17 and in_play:
            self.dealer.add_cards(self.shoe.deal(1))
            sleep(0.5)
            self.print_board()

        payout = self.get_payout()
        self.bankroll += payout
        print(f'You received a payout of ${payout}')
        if premium and self.dealer.get_hand()[1].get_value() == 10:
            self.bankroll += premium * 2
            print(f'You received an insurance payout of ${premium * 2}')

    def play(self) -> None:
        more = True
        while more and self.bankroll >= self.min_bet:
            self.num_round += 1
            self.round()
            more = self.get_bool_input('Do you want to play more rounds [Y/n]? ', 'YN')
            if (ls := self.shoe.get_length()) < 15:
                msg = f"Only {ls} cards left in dealer's shoe. "
                msg += "Do you want to replenish the shoe [Y/n]? "
                if self.get_bool_input(msg, 'YN'):
                    self.shoe = self.generate_shoe()
                else:
                    print("Game Over (too few cards remaining)")
                    break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Blackjack()
```

Feel free to tell me anything that I could improve my code, style, etc, and anything I should, or shouldn't have done. Lastly, I'd like to know what kind of speed I should aim for. This took some hours for me to code (1 < h < 10). Should I aim for < 60 minutes? or < 30 mins? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: [this](https://github.com/e1630m/blackjack/blob/main/blackjack.py) is a link to the most recent version of my blackjack code for anyone who is interested.

Comment: is the program exclusive to unix runtime?

Comment: @hjpotter92 No. AFAIK, it works everywhere. But it may not run on vanilla PyCharm due to `os.system()` and `os.get_terminal_size()`.

Comment: it won't work on windows/powershell too, due to the color code and symbols.

Comment: Strange because I've tested on 3 different Windows environments. [1](https://i.imgur.com/77wpdg4.png) [2](https://i.imgur.com/EvgQs60.png) [3](https://i.imgur.com/0o8bh0k.png)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq8XA.png this is in the plain powershell provided and is not the fluent based windows terminal

Comment: I believe that's just a font-related problem as some fonts don't have the `♤♡♢♧` unicode characters. If you use `sdict = {'S': '♠', 'H': '♥', 'D': '♦', 'C': '♣'}`, it'll work on [pwsh.exe](https://i.imgur.com/ekxbE6y.png) as well as [powershell.exe](https://i.imgur.com/Ej6VrEB.png)

Comment: I don't understand  where is defined variable `list`? Because  `def display(self, hide=0) -> list[str]:` gives error `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: @JosefZ I have the same problem. I believe this might be a python-version issue, since I think the type-weenies are pushing to get things like this to work. `list` is, of course, a built-in function when it's not being treated as a Subscriptable.

Comment: @JosefZ That's type hints. You can either a) remove `list[str]` and `list[Card]` thing everywhere, or b) use python 3.9 or above, or c) use python 3.5 or above and do this `from typing import List` and change `list[str]` to `List[str]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Planning ahead

> It is very messy but I always ended up like this somehow. Maybe it's because I usually don't plan anything ahead and just dive right into coding, but then again, I don't know what exactly I should plan ahead.

I recommend to work in baby steps.
Think of the next valuable feature, in its simplest form,
and implement just that.
When you are done with a baby step, pause and take a step back,
review what you did considering the bigger picture of your ultimate goal,
and verify that you're still going in the right direction, or else revert.

For example here, I would first implement the most basic game possible,
without many of the features you currently have:

- no fancy output, no colors
- no shoe feature
- play just one game
- implement the essential rules only, without payout, insurance, etc
- ... and so on ...

If that had been your first post,
reviewers could have focused on the high level design,
and could have provided early guidance to prevent going down paths that are not very useful and time consuming.

#### Keeping things simple

Every piece of code is a burden.
It has to be understood and maintained.
Therefore it's important that every piece of code is useful.

If you don't fully understand why something is there, I suggest to delete it.
If the program doesn't work without it, try to understand why.

---

> `uid` is doing nothing currently but I put it there just in case.

Drop it. It's not useful. The reader has to understand it, and in fact there's nothing to understand, because it really has no purpose right now.
It's a friction for the reader at every occurrence of `uid` in this program.
For example:

- When reading the constructor of `Card`, I'm wondering what is this for.
- When trying to create a `Card`, I'm wondering what value I should pass, and what will be the consequences.

If it's not there, I save many unnecessary mental cycles.

---

Remove anything that is not used.
For example `Card.get_suit`.

Another example is the `colored` parameter of `get_symbol`: the function is only ever called with `colored=1`, so the parameter is not useful.

Do this recursively, after you removed something,
check what else has become unused.
For example, after removing `Card.get_suit`,
it turns out that `self.suit` is also not used.

If you had built up the code from scratch only adding what is absolutely necessary in each step,
then there would be less to remove now,
less code to review and to understand,
therefore less mental burden.

---

`Card.display` is extremely hard to understand and to maintain.
If there was a separate template for each card,
that would be easy to understand and to maintain,
even if that will make the program longer,
it would be a good tradeoff.

Optimize code for reading, first.
If there are problems with that,
fix it in a later step, if really important.

#### Avoid recomputing values that are not supposed to change

For example `Card.get_symbol` will recompute the symbol on every call,
based on values that never change after the card is created.
It would be better to compute this only once,
at the time the card is created.
The same goes for `Card.get_rank`, `Card.__str__`.

#### Avoid duplicated logic

This code pattern appears in many places in `Card`:

> ```
> Card.color['r'] + something + Card.color['w']
> ```

It would be better to extract this logic to a common function with a descriptive name.
It will make it easier to understand the code,
and if you need adjust the logic in the future,
you will be able to do it in one place.

#### Hide implementation details

`Hand.set_hand_value` is only used internally within `Hand`.
It should not never be called from outside.
To signal this to readers, rename with a single underscore `_` prefix.

#### Consider real life objects to guide your design

`Hand.add_cards` looks strange, because the name is plural.
When in a game of Blackjack do we ever add more than one card to the hand?
I think never, so this is confusing.

An `add_card` function that takes a single `Card` parameter would be natural.

#### Other technical Python coding issues

Several methods in `Card` take a `colored` parameter with values 0 or 1, and used in boolean context. The parameter should be a proper boolean.

---

The `if self.hand else 0` is unnecessary:

> ```
> self.hand = [] if hand is None else hand
> self.total_value = sum(c.get_value() for c in self.hand) if self.hand else 0
> self.num_aces = sum(c.get_value() == 11 for c in self.hand) if self.hand else 0
> ```

You asked if it would be better to make only one pass over `self.hand`,
and compute `total_value` and `num_aces` in that loop.
Yes, one pass is usually better than 2.

---

Instead of the many `get_` methods,
consider using [properties](https://realpython.com/python-property/).

Comment: `Hand.add_cards`: I'm not familiar with blackjack, and I thought they initially deal 2 cards at once and then start to deal one card (just like I did on `Blackjack.round`). After watching a few blackjack tournament videos, I realized that's not the case.

Comment: `if self.hand else 0`: I put it there because `sum(None)` will break when `hand is None` (this happens on `Blackjack.__init__`). I could just start with something like `hand = [] if hand is None else hand` and remove `if else` for those three variables, or change `self.dealer` and `self.player` on `Blackjack.__init__` to be initialized with a dummy card, or remove the `self.dealer` and `self.player` from `Blackjack.__init__` altogether and call new instance of `Hand` with a card every round. I'm going to modify my code for the last option.

Comment: @e1630m `self.hand = [] if hand is None else hand` makes sure that `self.hand` is not `None`, and that's why you don't need the `if self.hand else 0` on the next two lines

Comment: Oops. I mistakenly wrote the comment after checking the slightly modified version that does the job in one sweep but iterates over `hand` not `self.hand`.

Answer (score 3):

- Don't inherit from `(object)`; Python 2 needs to die (and you already rely on Python 3 given your current code)
- An OO approach would have a `Suit` class (even if it's a lightweight named tuple) with properties of, perhaps: symbol, name, letter, colour. This is a little less awkward than `is_red`. These properties can then be factored away from `Card`, and only a reference to a suit object kept for each card.
- Having the `color` dictionary on `Card` doesn't make much sense; you'll want to have a module or class that takes care of screen operations such as clear, and ANSI escape sequences for colour etc.
- The pattern `Card.color['r'] + self.symbol + r + Card.color['w']` calls out for a utility or two. One pattern you could follow is a `@contextmanager` that sets the colour, runs the inner code, and then clears the colour after (even if an exception is thrown).
- You have some typehints - good! But they're inconsistent. For instance,

```
    def get_symbol(self, colored=0) -> str:
```

needs a hint for `colored`. Since you asked, your `hand=None` should be `hand: Optional[List[Card]] = None`.

- Your `Blackjack` constructor shouldn't be responsible for running the entire game; just initialisation.
- The call `self.dealer.__init__()` is concerning. Presumably that object is already initialised via `Hand()`, so - calling it again is surprising. If you just want to replace the instance, replace the instance.
- `length`, `is_busted` etc. are a good fit to be `@property`s. The purpose of a property is not particularly to do a character-by-character code length trade; it's to communicate to callers of your class that certain values from your class are available without needing to pass parameters, ideally without mutating the class, and without a whole lot of computation. Properties are also convenient when using modern debuggers as they appear without having to be explicitly called.
- You have some manually-formatted currency strings. [locale.currency](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html#locale.currency) is made for this.
- `self.bankroll // 1000 // 1000 * 1000` seems like you're doing a little bit of trickery to get a round effect. That's less obvious than just calling [round](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round). You say *I was trying to give two different `min_bet` for users. $5 for someone with less than $1 million bankroll, and roughly 0.1% of bankroll rounded down to a thousand dollars for someone with a million or above bankroll.* Clear code for this behaviour is important (also, don't name a variable `d`):

```
if self.bankroll < 1e6:
    default = self.min_bet
else:
    default = round(self.bankroll/1000, -3)
```

- `user_input < lo or user_input > hi` is equivalent to `not (lo <= user_input <= hi)`
- Apparently this is [controversial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87251/use-m-for-million-instead-of-m), but my opinion is that $100m is ten cents. $100M is 100 million dollars.

Comment: `(object)`: Thanks. I didn't know `(object)` was a Python 2 thing. I saw some classes have these bits, while some don't, and started to put it everywhere without any understanding.

Comment: **Type hints**: I didn't know how to use type hints with default parameters. Hence, `colored=0` as well as `opt='YN'`, `rv=22`, `hi=6`, `minimum=0.30`, etc. Now I figured it out how to use it (for example, `opt: str = 'YN'`), but still `Hand.__init__` kinda bugs me, since `hand: list = None` looks somewhat weird to me.

Comment: `@property decorator`: Is there a reason to use this? It would add one line for each `is_something()` and remove two characters `()` when I call it, which doesn't sound like a good trade to me. If I replace getters, I would earn 4 more spaces on each time I call it  (by removing `get_`), but still doesn't look like a sweet deal. Is it primarily used to narrow down multiple options (to access attribute) to one? Or is there a way to merge multiple getters into one universal getter?

Comment: `self.bankroll // 1000 // 1000 * 1000`: I was trying to give two different `min_bet` for users. $5 for someone with less than $1 million bankroll, and roughly 0.1% of bankroll rounded down to a thousand dollars for someone with a million or above bankroll. I could achieve the same outcome with `__import__('math').floor(self.bankroll // 1e6 * 1e3)` or `int(self.bankroll // 1e6 * 1e3)`, but opted for that one. Maybe I should just settle for universal 0.1% minimum bet with an absolute minimum of $5 (something like `min(5, round(self.bet // 1000)`).

Comment: _[it] doesn't sound like a good trade to me_ - because counting individual characters like that is not really the overriding criterion. I've edited my answer with a little more explanation. _Is it primarily used to narrow down multiple options (to access attribute) to one? Or is there a way to merge multiple getters into one universal getter?_ No, and 'technically yes but it would be more work than benefit'.